# Existing full ajax jQuery site must become search engine friendly?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, seo

I've built a **full** ajax site using jQuery and asp.net. All database data are loaded dynamically via client-side ajax calls. There are no html forms or postbacks, just ajax calls to a web service returning (xml) data.

Now, I need to make the site SEO friendly with emphasis to google. What is the least time expensive way to do it? Is there a way jQuery or asp.net can help me with out-of-the-box solutions/components etc? On the other hand, there is the [google specification](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) but is it standard or easy to implement in my case?

Any help or ideas much appreciated.

Comment: i guess noone knows or cares?

Answer (score 1):

your question is kinda unspecific.

jquery is javascript - based on how it's implemented can be very bad for SEO
asp.net is server side - can be anything, what counts is the HTML you have on page.

for a start i would recommend googling your site, then click on the "cached" link below it, then "text only version" ... this is what google sees. if you can makes sense of it, then google can make sense of it. if there is nothing there (possible for a very very ajaxy site) then well you are in trouble. then go to your competitiors site and do the same. if he is doing a better job look at his HTML sourcecode and think about ways you can get in this direction.

you would maybe also like to take a look at http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html